# stop disappearing md-dialog box after clicking confirm button

Tags: angularjs

Here I'm Using `md-dialog` box `prompt()` method of angular- material so after clicking OK button it returns promises where .then's resolve function (the first parameter) is when `.hide()` is called and the `md-dialog` box disappear.

Can anyone please suggest me how can I resolve function without calling `.hide()` method.

Here is my code.

```
$scope.parentNumberOTPVerification = function(ev,name,mobileNumber,email) {
    // Appending dialog to document.body to cover sidenav in docs app
            storeService.otpSender(name,mobileNumber,email)
            var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
                .title('Please Provide Your OTP')
                .placeholder('OTP')
                .targetEvent(ev)
                .ok('Verify')

            $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(result) {
                //console.log("result:",result)
            }, function() {
                $scope.status = 'You didn\'t name your dog.';
            });
        };
```

so what i want when i'm hiting ok button of the dialog box first function execute and dialog box hide. have there any way to stop that hidding?

Comment: add code which you have tried.

Comment: Edited.........